# Converting a .storyboard file into raw swift code in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

Is there a program that can take a `.storyboard` file, and convert it into Swift code? An example being: If I have a `UIViewImage` element in my storyboard can the program identify the element and convert it into swift, then insert that code into my `viewcontroller.swift` file? (Just an example.)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, no.

There's this rather *old* [nib2objc](https://github.com/akosma/nib2objc) tool that convert from NIBs to Objective C code. But no Storyboard -> Swift tool that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for the same thing, I discovered this tool and ran the demo on one of my Xcode 10-14 era storyboard files. It seems to work as advertised, including having an interactive mode that allows highlighting sections to find what corresponds:

https://www.microcodingapps.com/

*Disclaimer: I have no connection with this app or whoever makes it and have only taken a cursory look at it so far, but I was impressed enough with what I saw to come back to this SO article and add an answer.*